# Firestore Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am not receiving any callback from interfaces such as `addOnSuccessListener`, `addOnFailureListener`,`addOnCompleteListener`.

Dependencies:

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
       // }
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Code:

```
 firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); // required for first time 
    FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
            .build();
    firestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("Title", "Ada");
            user.put("category", "Lovelace");
            user.put("id", "123");

            firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firestore.collection("quotes")
                    .add(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            Log.d("quotes", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                            Snackbar.make(fab, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w("quotes", "Error adding document", e);
                            Snackbar.make(fab, "OnFailureListener: " + e, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                            Snackbar.make(fab, "OnCompleteListener: " + task.isSuccessful(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

> > > LOGCAT

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
```

Comment: Are you using Firebase Cloud Messaging in your app? Because that's where I'd expect messages with `FirebaseInstanceId` to come from.

Comment: Rebuild your project after changing `google-services.json`

Answer (score 41):

If you have recently change your `google-services.json` file then just delete `build` folder from android project and re-build your project.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.2'
```

And also don't forget to add the following dependecy which is now mandatory:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

Also if you need to use `Firebase Messaging` then you should also add the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Comment: This is not a valid answer: I have the latest versions and still get INVALID_SENDER error.

Comment: @ildarishalin By the time I answered this question, this answer worked. It's tested. Now you should update your dependencies to the latest version.

Comment: As I said, I'm using the latest versions. The real answer for me was to switch from OnSuccessListener to OnCompleteListener

Comment: In my case the google-services.json file was old. I mean by this is I registrated my project two times for two separate Google accounts. I think one of the filed in your google-services.json file is wrong. Try to reregister your project! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is very dumb but,

```
See if google-services.json is correct.
```

I was using google-services.json from another project.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. It had nothing to do with my code but rather with API key, check that everything from that side is up and working. (My problem was about google billing account).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Turned out a team member had accidentally deleted the Firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply but you will get correct sender is from firebase.

Got to firebase-> Select your project->Project setting->Cloud Messaging->Sender ID

You will get your sender_id , copy that and use in your prroject it will solve your issue.

Comment: Where to copy that sender ID

Comment: Where I should copy the sender ID?

Answer (score 0):

Your `buildVariant` should be same as project in Firebase. Check `buildTypes` and productFlavors.

Answer (score 0):

If Using Flutter Fire

NOTE - Use this "Firebase.initializeApp" only Once in the entire Project.

Wait for the Default Firebase app to initialize

```js
  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'YourAPP',
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    ).whenComplete(() {
      print("completedAppInitialize");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete Project (App_Folder_Name)/app/ "build"

delete entire build folder and rebuild it it will work. If only your jason file is correct

Answer (score -1):

Dont Use with Flutter Fire

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(

    // name: 'DontUseThis',

    // Note --^ Gives error of duplicate app if using only 1 app.
```

And also shows the [firebase_messaging]

> Failed to get FIS auth token error
> FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry
>
> E/FirebaseInstanceId( 8503): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: FIS_AUTH_ERROR. Won't retry the operation.

Avoid using "Name" parameter field.