# Firebase not detecting my flutter app, and unable to send push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

Firebase is not detecting my android app(in the setup section, the last step which is 'run your app to verify installation'). I am not able to send notifications to the app as well. I have imported all the important packages(core and messaging), and have done everything according to this [Medium](https://medium.com/@viveky259259/flutter-firebase-notifications-7954a3ad8111) article. I have also checked many stackoverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987032/firestore-token-retrieval-failed-invalid-sender). But still, I am not able to receive push notifications in my device(genymotion emulator).
There is an error which says:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId( 7264): Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure 
exceptions: INVALID_SENDER. Won't retry the operation.
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264): getToken, error fetching instanceID:                                             
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264): java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER                                              
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:71)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:84)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
com.google.firebase.iid.zzp.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:4)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown 
Source)                    
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)                                   
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264): getToken, error fetching instanceID:                                             
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264): java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER                                              
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:71)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
com.google.firebase.iid.zzl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:84)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
com.google.firebase.iid.zzp.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.0.2:4)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown 
Source)                    
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/FirebaseMessagingPlugin( 7264):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: As mentioned below, make sure that the google-services.json is included in the application in the right location. Also, try running a flutter clean. If the issue still persists can you include a snippet of the code initializing FCM?

Comment: yes running flutter clean solved the problem. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the google-services.json to the project.